# Search linkedlist for object variable

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to search a LinkedList and compare the objects in the list so I don't add duplicates. I can't figure out how to pull a node so I can compare it to the StudentInfo object I'm trying to add. This is my attempt to use an iterator:

```
private LinkedList<CourseInfo> classes = new LinkedList<>();

  public void addCourse(String cid, String name, String prof, String days, 
  String time, String room)
  {

     CourseInfo course = new CourseInfo(cid, name, prof, days, time, room);
     Iterator i = classes.iterator();
     while(i.hasNext())
     {
         if(i.equals(course))
         {
             System.out.println("Caught");
             break;
         }

     }

 }
```

I specifically need to compare the cid variables

Comment: Don't want duplicates: use `HashSet`.  Find an object: `list.contains(...)`.

Comment: Did you override `equals()` and `hashcode()` in your `CourseInfo` class?

Answer (score 2):

Minor note, traversing a `LinkedList` to check if an element exists is expensive. You might want to consider [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). That being said, in your code you are comparing the `iterator` with the `CourseInfo`, you need to compare the element pointed by the `iterator` instead by using [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). Also, `next()` is required in order to advance the iterator (thanks to [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1440565/code-apprentice) for the suggestion) otherwise you could end up in an infinite loop in `i.hasNext()`.

```
private LinkedList<CourseInfo> classes = new LinkedList<>();

  public void addCourse(String cid, String name, String prof, String days, 
  String time, String room)
  {

     CourseInfo course = new CourseInfo(cid, name, prof, days, time, room);
     // Don't use raw types e.g. Iterator it
     // Specify the type of element you are iterating on
     // Iterator<T> it
     Iterator<CourseInfo> i = classes.iterator();
     while(i.hasNext())
     {
         CourseInfo cInfo = i.next(); // get the element pointed by the iterator
         if(cInfo.equals(course))
         {
             System.out.println("Caught");
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Or using [enhanced for-loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes):

```
for(CourseInfo ci : classes) {
    if(ci.equals(course)) {
        System.out.println("Caught");
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: it says incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to CourseInfo

Comment: @I.McFee I forgot to specify the `Type` in the Iterator<CourseInfo> and due to [type-erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) it becomes `Object` I've updated my answer. Take a look and let know if it works

Comment: `tmp` is probably the worst imaginable variable name.

Comment: Note that the call to `next()` is required in order to advance the iterator. The original while loop would continue indefinitely without this.

Comment: @DavidConrad good point. Thanks for your feedback! I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, you are absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm afraid that's still not working. I tried applying it to ehat i need it for, and it will not catch repeats:

Comment: CourseInfo course = new CourseInfo(cid, name, prof, days, time, room);
     Iterator<CourseInfo> i = classes.iterator();
     boolean keepOn = true;
     while(i.hasNext())
     {
         CourseInfo cInfo = i.next(); // get the element pointed by the iterator
         if(cInfo.equals(course))
         {
             System.out.println("Caught");
             keepOn = false;
             break;
         }    
     }
         if(keepOn)
         {
             classes.add(course);
         }
     }

Comment: @I.McFee You should edit your question with an update so that you can format the code correctly. This answer assumes that you already overrode the `equals()` and `hashcode()` method correctly.

Comment: @I.McFee are you [overriding equals & hashcode](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/) for `CourseInfo`?